# Simulating HTTP post request using requests module is not working

Tags: python, http

I tried to retrieve a page after submitting the form in the following link (with default options): https://selfservice.pasadena.edu/prod/pw_psearch_sched.p_search

I realized that the form is post method, so I used requests module to simulate a post request.

```
r = requests.post(URL, data=form_data).text
```

For the form data, I extracted using chrome developer tool.

```
form_data = {
    'TERM': '202070',
    'TERM_DESC': 'Fall 2020',
    'sel_subj': 'dummy',
    'sel_day': 'dummy',
    'sel_schd': 'dummy',
    'sel_camp': 'dummy',
    'sel_ism': 'dummy',
    'sel_sess': 'dummy',
    'sel_instr': 'dummy',
    'sel_ptrm': 'dummy',
    'sel_attrib': 'dummy',
    'being_hh': '5',
    'begin_mi': '0',
    'begin_ap': 'a',
    'end_hh': '11',
    'end_mi': '0',
    'end_ap': 'p',
    'aa': 'N',
    'bb': 'N',
    'ee': 'N'
}
```

But it keeps giving me `404 Error`.

At first, I tried to use `selenium` to simulate clicking the submit button but it is way too slow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 404 is a Not Found error.  You're posting to the wrong url.  What url are you using?

Comment: `form` doesn't have to send data to the same url. If you use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab: `Network`) then you see it sends to url https://selfservice.pasadena.edu/prod/pw_psearch_sched.p_listthislist

Comment: BTW: some servers check if you send correct headers and if you have cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

1. form sends to different url: https://selfservice.pasadena.edu/prod/pw_psearch_sched.p_listthislist
2. small mistake in name `'begin_hh'` - you have `'being_hh'`

---

Working code

```
import requests

data = {
    'TERM': '202070',
    'TERM_DESC': 'Fall 2020',
    'sel_subj':   'dummy',
    'sel_day':    'dummy',
    'sel_schd':   'dummy',
    'sel_camp':   'dummy',
    'sel_ism':    'dummy',
    'sel_sess':   'dummy',
    'sel_instr':  'dummy',
    'sel_ptrm':   'dummy',
    'sel_attrib': 'dummy',

    'sel_crse': '',
    'sel_crn': '',
    'sel_title': '',

    'begin_hh': '5',
    'begin_mi': '0',
    'begin_ap': 'a',
    'end_hh': '11',
    'end_mi': '0',
    'end_ap': 'p',
    'aa': 'N',
    'bb': 'N',
    'ee': 'N',
}

URL = 'https://selfservice.pasadena.edu/prod/pw_psearch_sched.p_listthislist'
r = requests.post(URL, data=data)
print(r.status_code)
#print(r.text)
```

---

**BTW:** originally form sends two values for some fields and it would be

```
'sel_subj':   ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_day':    'dummy',
'sel_schd':   ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_camp':   ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_ism':    ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_sess':   ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_instr':  ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_ptrm':   ['dummy', '%'],
'sel_attrib': ['dummy', '%'],
```

but page works even if you send one value.

---

**BTW:** in `DevTool` you can get code for rpogram `curl` and later you can convert it to Python code using page https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: OH MY GOD, Thank you so much! That work like a charm. BTW the site is also amazing. I really appreciate